# Remove xml:ns tags from webservice(axis2) response

Tags: rest, apache-axis

I have a webserivce deployed using axis2. The method on the service class returns a string.

> public String getXML(){                return
>   "Hello..."; }

and the service is configured like this

```
<operation name="getXML">
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
        </operation>
```

when I call this service from browser(RESTful) I get response like this

```
<ns:getXMLResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.drugservice.xyz.com"><ns:return>&lt;response>Hello...&lt;/response></ns:return></ns:getXMLResponse>
```

I don't want the xml:ns around the response string. How can I do it? I want to the see the response as

```
<reponse>Hello...</response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got to use axis2 client API for this. Something like this

```
RPCServiceClient serviceClient = null;

            try {
                serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();
            } catch (AxisFault e) {
                throw e;
            }

            try {
                EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference("http://localhost/ws/services/drugService");

                // Authorizing access to the url
                QName action = new QName("http://service.drugservice.xyz.com", "getPricingImagesData");

                Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
                options.setTo(targetEPR);
                Object obj[] = new Object[] {"3885"};
                OMElement responseObject = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(action,obj);
                String response = responseObject.getFirstElement().getText();

                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (AxisFault e) {
                throw e;
            } finally {
                try {
                    serviceClient.cleanup();
                } catch (AxisFault e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
                try {
                    serviceClient.cleanupTransport();
                } catch (AxisFault e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
```